# Implement Comet / Server push in Google App Engine in Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, comet, server-push, channel-api

How can I implement Comet / Server push in Google App Engine in Python?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

We just announced the Channel API to do comet push with App Engine apps: http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2010/05/app-engine-at-google-io-2010.html

If you're at Google IO, I'll be talking about this at 1pm tomorrow (on the APIs track): http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/building-real-time-apps-app-engine-feed-api.html

Here's the YouTube video of the session: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oMXe-xK0BWA

Hopefully last update! This is now released: [code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel)

Comment: I'm sorry I had to miss that talk yesterday (too many good overlapping talks!). Any news on when we'll see documentation of this feature or when it'll be available for us to use?

Comment: The talk itself will be on YouTube next week (I think), and it contains details of the API. No specific dates for launch, but if you want to sign up for trusted tester you can go do so here: https://spreadsheets.google.com/viewform?formkey=dGFxQ1A4T1BSYWxNdFlYVFhUcmg2amc6MQ

Comment: Could you please link to the video?

Comment: As soon as the videos are posted to the Google IO site, I'll post a link here. (I am simultaneously looking forward to and dreading seeing myself on video...)

Comment: Wondering if you could give us an estimate when we can play with this :)?

Comment: Dotting i's and crossing t's... look for this very soon.

Answer (score 3):

At this time, I would rule out doing Comet in App Engine (any language). Comet is based on long-lived HTTP connections, and App Engine will time out any single connection in about 30 seconds or so at most; it's hard to conceive of a worse match!

Comment: This answer is no longer relevant. The one by Moishe is.

Comment: The answer by Moishe will be no longer relevant soon, Channel API is planned for shutdown in Oct 2017

Answer (score 2):

Comet (or something like it - XMPP API) is on the google app engine roadmap.  For now, stay away.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html

Comment: this is not helpful, although already released, the appengine can be used to build chat bots with this API, but it still doesn not allow for long-polling

Comment: you're right. another server is needed to translate the client-side long polling to XMPP messages. 

the recently release tornado framework looks like a good option!

Answer (score 1):

30 seconds is more than enough; either way you should return a no-op message when a time passed and no new events occur.

This prevents client timeouts and is done by everybody who does comet.

Just send the request, and on the server make it wait until an event or timeout after 25 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Looking inside the App Engine 1.3.8-pre release, I see the Channel API service stub and more code. So it looks like we can start trying it out locally.

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine supports server push using the Channel API since 2nd December.